# Express + Handlebars: Can't seem to find the right path to css file

Tags: css, node.js, express

Just for a student exercise I'm trying to get an API of presidents and style them. I have everything but the `style.css` linking.

I've tried many ways of changing the path and public path in the server.js as well as the `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` line and nothing so far has seemed to work. I need a hand from someone more experienced in Express and Handlebars. Thanks!

File structure:

```
/public
 . css
  .. styles.css
/views
 . layout.hbs
 . presidents.hbs
/index.html
/server.js
```

**server.js**

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

async function fetchAndParseData() {
  const r = await fetch('https://api.sampleapis.com/presidents/presidents');
  const data = await r.json();
  return data;
}

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// The method `.use` sets up middleware for the Express application
app.use(express.json());
// this parses requests that may use a different content type
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/presidents', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await fetchAndParseData();
  res.render('presidents', { data });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Presidents Site</h1>');
});

app.listen(4001, () => {
  console.log('SomeApp HTML');
});
```

**layout.hbs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Express HTML Site</title>
</head>
<body>
  {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

**presidents.hbs**

```
<h1>All our presidents</h1>
{{#each data}}

<section id="presidents">
<figure class="president">
  <img src={{this.photo}} alt={{this.name}}/>
  <caption>{{this.name}}</caption>
  </figure>
{{/each}}
</section>
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change from app.use(express...'public'))); to  app.use('/uploads', express.static(publicPath));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't see you `require` the handlebars package and set it up I will assume you have just omitted it from from `server.js` given that it's only the css you need help with.

Both of these should work equally as well:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

or

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

However, you still need to include the stylesheet link in your `layout.hbs` file like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
      <title>Express HTML Site</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     {{{body}}}
   </body>
</html>
```

At the minute it looks like you are only including them in your `index.html`